# Is this a homogenous reaction?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, phase

$$\ce{HCl(aq) + NaOH(aq) ->  NaCl(aq) + H2O(l)}$$
Would this reaction be considered homogenous even though there is a liquid in the products?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Chemistry.SE! You can get a good overview of how this side works by taking the short [tour]. For any questions you can visit the [help]. Also, as this appears to be a homework-type of question, I suggest reading through [this](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange/142#142) post regarding how to ask homework questions.  Best of luck!

Comment: What other phase is present besides liquid in the reaction? Is there one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be considered homogeneous, since all of the components are in water. We don't write water as being aqueous because it would be somewhat redundant to say the water formed in water.